# Converting dictionary to an object with keys as object's name in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'item1': ('Hi', (150, 495)), 'item2': ('Hola', (590, 40))}
```

I want to convert it to object, recursively if possible. I have a class:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self,thetuple):
    self.greeting=thetuple[0]
    self.coordinate=thetuple[1]
```

So what I want is, there should be an object, for instance item1, and item1.greeting is "Hi", item1.coordinate is (150,495) etc.

I'm open to all kinds of solutions, improvements, ideas. Thanks.

Comment: *recursively*? There is nothing recursive in the data... Recursion should be used for things that have an inductive nature.

Comment: This is a simple iteration through the dictionary, forming an object from each dictionary entry.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Professor asked us to take this dictionary and turn each key to an object in a function,with recursion. If I understood you correctly, the answer is there is no recursion in the data because I couldn't implement it.

Comment: @Prune I'm exactly stuck at that part, I try iteration but I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

So do something like this:

```
import collections

Item = collections.namedtuple('Item', ('greeting', 'coordinate'))

d = {'item1': ('Hi', (150, 495)), 'item2': ('Hola', (590, 40))}

new_d = {k: Item(*v) for k, v in d.items()}

# Now you can do

new_d['item1'].greeting == 'Hi'

new_d['item2'].coordinate == (590, 40)
```