# YAML config file with to class object

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a yaml configuration file (`configuration.yaml`).

Which I load using:

```
import yaml

configuration = load_configurations()
def load_configurations(path_configuration = "../input/configuration.yaml"):
    with open(path_configuration, "r") as stream:
        try:
            return(yaml.safe_load(stream))
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
```

Within `configuration` I have the following structure:

```
parameters:
   pmt1:
      value: 1.0
      description: some text
   pmt2:
      value: 0.03
      description: some other text
   pmt3:
      value: 0.033
      description: more text
...
...
   pmtN:
      value: 0.04
      description: yet more text
```

Now, **I would like to import these parameters as objects in a class whose value is the `value` taken from the configuration file.**

I read the [YAML documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) and following previously asked questions:

[Convert nested Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-nested-python-dict-to-object)

[Converting dictionary to an object with keys as object's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068723/3284713)

But I haven't been able to solve my issue.

**What I managed to do until now is:**

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, configuration):
        self.set_parameters(configuration)


    def set_parameters(self, configuration):
        self.__dict__ = configuration["parameters"]
```

Which works but only allows me to call something like:

```
In[]: MyClass.pmt1
Out[]: 
{'value': 1,
 'description': 'some text'}
```

**What I would like to get:**

```
In[]: MyClass.pmt1
Out[]: 1
```

I also tried to iterate through the dictionary items `for item in configuration['parameters'].items():` but that returns a tuple of the form:

```
('pmt1', {'value': 1.0, 'description': 'some text'})
```

but I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) rather than overwriting `__dict__`, which could have unexpected consequences.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, configuration):
        self.set_parameters(configuration)

    def set_parameters(self, configuration):
        for k, v in configuration["parameters"].items():
            setattr(self, k, v["value"])
```

Unless it's required to be able reset the instance's attributes, I'd set them inside `__init__` and avoid the method call:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, configuration):
        for k, v in configuration["parameters"].items():
            setattr(self, k, v["value"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do since I don't know what `In[]` / `Out[]` means and you don't show your entire code, but I guess you're looking for something like

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, configuration):
        self.set_parameters(configuration)


    def set_parameters(self, configuration):
        self.__dict__ = {k:v.value for (k,v) in configuration["parameters"].items()}
```

Comment: `In[] / Out[]` looks like the iPython repl.